# How to get last Id that contain HardwarId

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I got an issue to reclaim `Hardware` that has exact ID (e.g. `ID=5`). There is my code:

```
class HardwareTransfer{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public ICollection<Hardware> Hardwares { get; set; }
}

class Hardware{
 public int Id { set; get; }
 public string Title { set; get; }
}
```

How to get last `HardwareTransfer.Id` of `HardwareTransfer`, that contains `Hardwares.Id = 5`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask], create a [mcve] including example input and output and show what you have tried, even if that didn't work. It's probably going to look like `transfer.Hardwares.LastOrDefault(h => h.Id == 5)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this code

```
//_listHardwareTransfer is a List Of HardwareTransfer
var maxId=_listHardwareTransfer.Where(x => x.Hardwars.Contains(5)).Max(x => x.Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways how you can obtain this. By using LINQ (preferred way):

```
myHardwareTransfer.Hardwares.Last(a => a.Id == 5);
```

In C#:

```
Hardware lastFound;
foreach(var nHardware in myHardwareTransfer.Hardwares)
    if(nHardware.Id == 5)
        lastFound = nHardware;
```

Comment: tanks for your answer but i need HardwareTransfer's Id , not Hardware Id

Comment: @ZahraNaderiqaraqeshlaq In that case the question is unclear. You should provide what objects You have. Is there a list of `Transfers`? Or is there just one? That is what CodeCaster was refering under Your question - Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.